# Editing Copyright line in Apache2 license.txt

Tags: licensing, open-source, free-software, apache

I wish to publish my program under Apache2 license. I have added the    "APPENDIX" part of the license text to the top portion of my source.txt file and edited the copyright year and name.

But when I add the license.txt file in the same archive with sourcecode, should I edit the copyright line wih my name and year? Or should I let the copy of license.txt intact as downloaded from apache site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute your own copyright name and year - (from Apache license [documentation](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)):

> To apply the Apache License to your work, attach the following
>   boilerplate notice, with the fields enclosed by brackets "[]" replaced
>   with your own identifying information. (Don't include the brackets!)
>   The text should be enclosed in the appropriate comment syntax for the
>   file format. We also recommend that a file or class name and
>   description of purpose be included on the same "printed page" as the
>   copyright notice for easier identification within third-party
>   archives.
>
> ```
> Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
> you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
> You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
>     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
> distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
> WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
> See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
> limitations under the License.
> ```

Comment: "We also recommend that a file or class name and description of purpose be included on the same "printed page" as the copyright notice for easier identification within third-party archives." I don't understand this part, anyone know what this means?